# Is science data from astronomical telescopes analyzed with something analogous to "optical character recognition"?

Tags: software, raw-data, instruments

Do people manually input the science data from telescopes into databases or does some software automatically collect the data from telescopes and put it in servers and databases?

I'd imagine there's too much data from present-day telescopes that they can collect to handwrite or hand by hand input the data from them into spreadsheets therefore computers do it via machine learning?

Comment: What do you mean by "data" ? Telemetry from the telescope itself or science data from the instruments ?

Comment: @astrosnapper science data from instruments

Comment: I've made an edit to your question based on your comment above and to adjust some of the wording. Please feel free to edit further if you like.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FITS and http://nova.astrometry.net/upload don't answer your question but may help. https://www.cosmos.esa.int/web/gaia/data-processing notes that the GAIA project uses software to process raw images.

Comment: google.com/search?q=ai+galaxies&oq=ai+galaxies